# Trouble with sorting arrays with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I am trying to make my program display the original array and then sort it and display the sorted array with pointers, and then finally display the array in its original state.
So far I've gotten the original as well as the sorted array to display, however the third display shows up as the sorted array as well. But I need it to be in the original state.
I think I'm not using the pointers correctly and that I am actually changing the array, If someone could explain to me where the error is it would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printArrayO(int DataArr[], int size)
{
   // for loop used to print array contents 10 per line
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       if ((i % 10) == 0)
       {
          printf("\n");
       }// end of if statement
         // printing with a field size of 5
          printf("%*d", 5, DataArr[i]);
    }// end of for loop

    printf("\n");
}// end of void print function


void bubbleSortArray(int ArrPoint[], int size)
{
   double temp;   // temporary variable

    // for loops used to sort the numbers
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // check if this is right for first for loop
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1) - i; j++)
      {
         if (ArrPoint[j] > ArrPoint[j + 1])
         {
            temp = ArrPoint[j];
            ArrPoint[j] = ArrPoint[j + 1];
            ArrPoint[j + 1] = temp;
         }// end of if statement
      }// end of nested for loop
   }// end of for loop

}// end of void bubble sort function */



// print array function
void printArray(int ArrPoint[], int size)
{
   // for loop used to print array contents 10 per line
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        // possible make a count variable and then use it to make a new line if   %10 ==0
       if ((i % 10) == 0)
       {
          printf("\n");
       }// end of if statement
         // printing with a field size of 5
          printf("%*d", 5, ArrPoint[i]);
    }// end of for loop

    printf("\n");
}// end of void print function



int main()
{
    // given numbers for the main array
    int DataArr[150] = {71, 1899, 272, 1694, 1697, 296, 722, 12, 2726, 1899,
1374, 1541, 1923, 1904, 1083, 1462, 2981, 1929, 304, 2550,
1059, 1860, 1963, 516, 647, 1607, 590, 157, 2351, 753,
2455, 349, 79, 1634, 368, 1992, 2401, 357, 1478, 1601,
239, 365, 2453, 2283, 2432, 1223, 2739, 2487, 2714, 1391,
1972, 2805, 1504, 413, 1647, 2750, 44, 64, 934, 1008,
1429, 1427, 315, 2499, 1620, 1816, 2441, 2557, 2188, 531,
1514, 2825, 449, 265, 2064, 1022, 34, 1864, 1861, 1516,
1465, 2327, 398, 2769, 563, 194, 429, 942, 1795, 223,
2406, 780, 780, 61, 133, 195, 495, 1774, 1934, 2171,
433, 1417, 292, 324, 2929, 1597, 1470, 764, 593, 891,
679, 47, 1778, 2532, 1862, 2636, 549, 2923, 2270, 1101,
1607, 2395, 726, 1111, 892, 1988, 555, 379, 224, 298,
1660, 2203, 2385, 2159, 2574, 705, 2513, 1755, 313, 173,
148, 2449, 259, 1006, 1221, 2259, 2020, 1484, 2717, 2400};



// array of int pointers
int *Arrpoint = &DataArr;
int *Arrpoint2 = &DataArr;
// *pointer[i] to use;


printf("Array in the original order");
printf("\n");
printArrayO(DataArr[150], 150);


printf("\n");
printf("Array after being sorted \n");
bubbleSortArray(Arrpoint[150], 150);
printArray(Arrpoint[150], 150);

printf("\n");
printf("Array in original order again \n");
printArrayO(DataArr[150], 150);





return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code has bugs all over it causing Undefined Behaviour. For example, `printArrayO(DataArr[150], 150);` is a buffer overflow (valid indexes are from 0 to 149). And that's entirely wrong anyway as `DataArr[i]` is an `int` but the function requires an `int *`. Many of those bugs should not be there if you take heed of your compiler warnings and fix all of those up. Suggest you do that and repost your question.

Comment: `Arrpoint` is **not** an array of int pointers. Neither is `Arrpoint2`. And `Arrpoint[150]` is an out-of-bounds read, it's *not* the whole array.

Comment: A good starting point would be to enable compiler warnings, then *eliminate them all* before asking for help.

Comment: The functions `printArray0` and `printArray` are identical. That should have warnen you, that both `DataArray` and `ArrPoint` contain integers.

Answer (score 0):

`int* Arrpoint = &DataArr` does not make a copy of `DataArr`. It simply makes `Arrpoint` point to `DataArr`, so whatever changes you do through `Arrpoint` will be reflected in `DataArr`.

You must copy the array to do what you want in this case.

```
int a[5]={5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
int* b = malloc(5*sizeof(*b));       // making new array b
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) b[i]=a[i];  // copying a to b
print(a, 5);                       // display a (unsorted)
sort(b, 5);                       // your sort function
print(b, 5);                     // display b (sorted)
print(a, 5);                    // display a (unsorted)
```

Comment: This question was about C, not C++.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the last line.  Other than that, I think it will compile in C99.  Earlier versions of C don't allow the declaration within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One use of pointers in C is to pass an array to a function, but if you do that your one and only copy of the array can be changed forever, unless the function only prints the array.

To do what you want you could have,

```
const int nums[150],unsorted[150],sorted[150];
```

Then 4 steps,

1. Initialize nums.
2. Copy nums to unsorted.
3. Pass unsorted to function(), which returns pointer to sorted.
4. Print nums, sorted, unsorted.